# Why is this getting data only from the 2nd HTML table row?

Tags: javascript, html

It was getting all the data when I was grabbing the table by its id, but I had to give the `tbody` an ID, because the actual table contains a footer with a total row. So, I thought I'd restrict getting the rows that really matter, but this is not getting the data from the first row now.

Any hint?

```js
function savePo() {
  let table = document.getElementById("tableRows");
  let [, ...tr] = table.querySelectorAll("tr");
  let tableData = [...tr].map(r => {
    let td = r.querySelectorAll("td");
    let test = [...td].map((c, j) => j == 9 ? (c.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')[0].checked) : j == 8 ? c.innerText : c.querySelector('input').value)
    console.log("check " + test);
    return test;
  });
  console.log('Table Data: ' + tableData);
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-vcenter" id="dtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:18%">Col 1</th>
      <th style="width:15%">Col 2</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Col 3</th>
      <th style="width:15%">Col 4</th>
      <th style="width:7%">Col 5</th>
      <th style="width:5%">Col 6(gsm)</th>
      <th style="width:7%">Col 7 (COP)</th>
      <th style="width:8%">Col 8 (m)</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Col 9</th>
      <th style="width:5%">Col 10</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='tableRows'>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="fdfdfdfd"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="fsfdsfsfd"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="100cot"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="item-table-values" name="numberInputs" value="1.63"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="item-table-values" name="numberInputs" value="273"></td>
      <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" class="price" name="numberInputs" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="178" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
      <td class="total_price"><strong>$0.00</strong></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="ererewr"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="vcbchbdgfh"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="1f23dfdsn"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="item-table-values" name="numberInputs" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="item-table-values" name="numberInputs" value="267"></td>
      <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" class="price" name="numberInputs" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="176" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
      <td class="total_price"><strong>$0.00</strong></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onClick=savePo()>
  Save PO
</button>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santosonit/1ghryfz9/39/#&togetherjs=C4Vy6oHp2f)

Appreciate your help!

Comment: What exactly do you think `let [, ...tr] =` does? Would it be clearer if you wrote that as `let [firstRow, ...otherRows] =`

Comment: Why go through all the trouble? `const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#tableRows tbody tr")`